# Why my custom Laravel Route is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am a noob in laravel but never faced this issue in my previous 1-2 projects. I don't know why my custom route is not working, while the welcome route working fine. This is first-time I am getting this error **404**  page not found.

web.php

```
Route::any('/dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@tempirelounge')->name('dashboard');
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function tempirelounge()
    {
        return view('admin/index');
    }
}
```

And the weird thing is that when I am trying to do this,

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

It is not working
but when I do this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

It is working fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Try: `Route::any('/dashboard', 'AdminController@tempirelounge')->name('dashboard');`. The namespace seems to be wrong defined in the routes file. Or change the namespace of the `AdminController` class

Comment: @ka_lin but this controller is in the Admin folder! will this work anyway?

Comment: The namespace of a controller should reflect the file location, if `AdminController` is in `app\Http\Controllers\Admin` then the namespace should be `namespace App\Http\Admin\Controllers`. After a namespace change (just for safety) run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @ka_lin the thing is that I am working on this setup on cpanel

Answer (score 2):

If your controller is in Admin folder then use correct name space.

Replace

```
App\Http\Controllers
```

with

```
App\Http\Controllers\Admin
```

Comment: you have placed Admin at wrong location it should come after Controllers like \Controllers\Admin not Admin\Controllers

Comment: `\Controllers\Admin\AdminController.php` is the location now and used your namespace as well, still not working!

Comment: it should work now, if not try running  composer optimize or php artisan route:clear  using cmd

Comment: this setup is on cpanel not on localhost so can't use cmd for this

Comment: Ahh..okay then do following...1. check if you have multiple Controller with same class name...this happen sometime when we make copy of controller file. like. AdminController.php and AdminController_Copy.php both will have same class name Admin Controller. Please remove one. 2. sometime  cpanel does this..Correct all errors. then rename root folder or if your application is in public_html then move application to sub folder and target your domain to point to new folder. This will force cpanel to run these two commands.

Comment: do you think we should also look for .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

your Controller namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`, and in route u use `... Controllers\Admin\AdminController@tempirelounge` where is true?

Comment: `Http/Admin/Controllers/` is where the controller is

Comment: `Http/Admin/Controllers/` a u sure? do u have any routes except this?)

Comment: if your Controller in `Admin/Controller`, u need to add new method in `RouteServiceProvider` with your admin namespace

Comment: ```protected function mapAdminWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace('App\Http\Admin\Controllers')
             ->group(base_path('routes/admin_web.php'));
    }``` like this) and put this method in `map()` method)

Comment: as per above answer, I changed the location now it is like  `\Controllers\Admin\AdminController.php` but still not working with your codes as well

Comment: if u move your controller in Controller/Admin u don't need all what I typing upper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210391/discussion-between-bohdan-petrenko-and-mohit-chandel).

Answer (score 0):

**Namespace is wrong**

**Approach 1:**

```
Route::any('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@tempirelounge')->name('dashboard');
```

**Approach 2:**

In web.php

use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController

```
Route::any('/dashboard', 'AdminController@tempirelounge')->name('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the route cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: this project is on cpanel